# setting up ZEND framework for php informix

Tags: zend-framework

Our organization builds web applications using PHP/Informix.
Currently we do not have any frameworks and use our own libraries and modules.

Now we set up a new apache web server so that we could install and configure a framework where all brand new web applications can be developed.
I was thinking of setting up the Zend Framework.(Will it go with informix backend?). I have googled and looked around for information , but I thought would get some expert opinions from the experts here.
I need some advice as how to go about from scratch the correct way.
Installing,configuring,setting up a version control and writing a script to test all basic MVC features.
Any suggestions and references would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Informix Dynamic Server as your backend, then yes you can use Zend Framework's native database classes and adapter for communicating with your Informix server.

Your requirements will be that PHP must be compiled with PDO support (enabled by default since PHP 5.1).  You then need to download, compile, and install the [PDO_IBM](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_IBM) Pecl package.

In order to successfully build the PDO_IBM extension, you must have the DB2 client (9.1+) installed on your system already.  When you compile the extension module, you must tell it the path to where those files are installed.

More information on [PDO_IBM](http://www.php.net/pdo-ibm), and [Zend_Db_Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html) talks a little bit about the available adapters (including PDO_IBM).

There is also a Pecl package [PDO_INFORMIX](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_INFORMIX) for talking to Informix servers, but Zend_Db does not support this package.  You will only be able to use `Zend_Db_Adapter` with `PDO_IBM` to communicate with IDS servers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So do I install PDO_IBM after I follow these instructions?http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/introduction.installation.html

Comment: Either before or after, you may want to make sure you can get the module built before you bother installing ZF.  It doesn't care either way.  If you try to create a DB adapter for IBM and you don't have it installed, you will get an exception saying the adapter is not installed.